# Unable to import or link MySQL - ODBC Call Failed

Tags: mysql, ms-access, odbc

I am attempting to import a database from a MySQL server. The steps I took to attempt this are:

1. Go into **External Data** -> **New Data Source** -> **From Database** -> **From SQL Server**
2. Specify to link the data source
3. Select a data source from **Machine Data Source**

This results in the error
"***ODBC -- call failed.
Specified driver could not be loaded due to system error 126: The specified module could not be found (MySQL ODBC 8.0 Unicode Driver, C:\Program FIles\MySQL\Connector ODBC 8.0\myodbc8w.dll). (#160)***"

This prevents me from importing data from the MySQL Server into a Microsoft Access database.

Comment: **C:\Program Files\..** sounds like a 64-bit driver. If you have 32-bit Office, you need the 32-bit driver (I think). You will also need to set up the DSN in the 32-bit ODBC manager of Windows.

Comment: Or the other way around. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version of Office was 64 bit whereas the ODBC driver was 32 bit.

Downloading and installing the 64bit driver from **https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/** fixed the issue